# Добавить стрелку к подсказке jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui

```
$(function() {
  $( tooltip ).tooltip({

    position: {
    my: "left+40 center",
    at: "right center",

    items: "[title]",
    content: function() {
      var element = $( this );

        if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "title" );
        }

      }
    }

  });
});
```

Выводит подсказку, а данный кусок кода отвечает за добавление стрелки слева от подсказки:

```
using: function( position, feedback ) {   
  $( this ).css( position );
  $( "<div>" )
    .addClass( "arrow" )
    .addClass( feedback.vertical )
    .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
    .appendTo( this );}
```

Как его правильно вписать в первый кусок кода, чтоб подсказка всплывала со стрелкой?

Comment: дык пример же на офф-сайте есть : https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style - вылазит по кнопочке `view source`

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из [tooltip #custom-style](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style), вот так:

```
$(function() {
  $( tooltip ).tooltip({
    position: {
      my: "left+40 center",
      at: "right center",
      using: function( position, feedback ) {   
        $( this ).css( position );
        $( "<div>" )
          .addClass( "arrow" )
          .addClass( feedback.vertical )
          .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
          .appendTo( this );}
      items: "[title]",
      content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "title" );
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```